# „Orbital“ of an quark

Tags: wavefunction, quarks, orbitals, strong-force, color-charge

Inspired by the idea of the electron orbitals ( probability of finding an electron in an atom) i was wondering what that would look like inside a proton or neutron for quarks. For simplicity consider a meson where we know the location of one quark. What is the orbital - or probability of finding the antiquark around this quark? Sure it must be in the range of about 1 fm, since this is the range of the strong force. Is it correct to postulate therefore that the antiquark orbital is a sphere of 1 fm in size? Next, we know that when quarks/antiquarks are very near together, the strong force gets weaker and diminishes. Can this possibly mean, that the probability of finding the antiquark in our meson goes here to zero? As result i would conclude that the orbtial of an antiquark around a localized quark in a meson look like this: The possibility of finding the antiquark is highest at a distance of 1 fm and then goes to zero as we approach the quark. Also, the probability of finding the antiquark outsite this 1 fm sphere is also zero. Of course things get more complicated when we treat both quark and antiquark in their orbital form so thats why i came up with that example.

Comment: The physics of QCD at a "low" energetic scale is so complicated that one rather looks at LQCD for bound states. Your idea is unlikely to be representative of a meson as described by the Standard Model.

Answer (score 1):

Unlike atomic electrons, the spin-orbit coupling in the strong interation is always non-negligible. If you know the spin and parity $J^P$ for a meson, you can figure out the *allowed* values for $L$. But in general, even a wavefunction which consists only of valence quarks will allow multiple values of $L$ to end up with an observed $J^P$. For a low-energy example, consider the two-nucleon deuteron, for which the spin $S=1$ is well-defined but whose orbital wavefunction contains a non-trivial mixture of s-wave and d-wave states.

In higher-energy hadron interactions, you must also consider the contributions of the gluons and the sea quarks, and you end up reinventing the parton distribution functions.